# Chrome multitouch support suddenly stopped

Tags: google-chrome, 15.04, multi-touch

I run Chrome 43.0.2357.65 on Ubuntu 15.10. I've had multi touch support working on my laptop for several months and today it suddenly stopped working. I'm not sure which chrome version I was on previously but I've tried various 43.X builds on Ubuntu 14.04, 14.10, and 15.04 and no dice. Maybe a flag changed somewhere. Previously I was successfully starting chrome with multitouch using the following arguments:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome --touch-events=enabled --enable-pinch --touch-devices=9
```

Touch is working just fine for all other touch enabled applications on Ubuntu :/

Comment: I experience the same issue on my Dell Inspiron 7548 with ubuntu 15.04. Before the latest chrome update everything was working fine but since few days it stopped. @sevenbitbyte have you already created a chrome ticket for this bug?

Comment: I've just opened an [issue here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=491939&thanks=491939&ts=1432575329)